# app check internet connection get force close when i try run in device

Tags: android, forceclose

Please, can any one check my code?

this my MainActivity

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity{

    CekKoneksi cekkoneksi;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);

        cekkoneksi = new CekKoneksi(getApplicationContext());

        new cekinternet().execute();
    }

    private class cekinternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //cekkoneksi = new CekKoneksi(getApplicationContext());

            if (cekkoneksi.isConnectingToNetwork()) {
                if (cekkoneksi.hasActiveInternetConnection())
                {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terkoneksi dengan Jaringan Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Terkoneksi dengan Jaringan tetapi tidak dengan Internet,\n Buka Setting dan Ubah Jaringan?")
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                                   startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                    exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    MenuActivity.this.finish();
                                    startActivity(exit);
                               }
                           });
                    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
             final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Tidak Tersambung dengan Jaringan Internet, Buka Setting dan Aktifkan Jaringan?")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                               startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                MenuActivity.this.finish();
                                startActivity(exit);
                           }
                       });
                final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Here class "CekKoneksi"

```
public class CekKoneksi {

    private Context cont;

    public CekKoneksi (Context context){
        this.cont = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToNetwork(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }


    public boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
     try {
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
                urlc.connect();
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
             Toast.makeText(cont, "Error checking internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        return false;
    }

}
```

this is the logcat

```
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:326)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:242)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at app.source.ensiklopedaitempatwisataindonesia.MenuActivity$cekinternet.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:109)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at app.source.ensiklopedaitempatwisataindonesia.MenuActivity$cekinternet.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:1)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-14 03:58:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(26427):    ... 5 more
```

In Manifest, I add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `Toast` and `AlertDialog` work into `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`. You cannot modify the UI from a background thread.